# Jasmine-javascript Testing the new open browser tab

Tags: javascript, testing, web, automated-tests, jasmine

I am really new to Jasmine testing language. I am trying to test some thing like this. (The following code works fine but my situation is a little bit different)

```
describe('Phone list view', function() {

 beforeEach(function() {
   browser().navigateTo('../../app/index.html#/phones');
 });
 it('should render phone specific links', function() {
     input('query').enter('nexus');
     element('.phones li a').click();
     expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/phones/nexus-s');
 });
});
```

When I run the line:

```
element('.phones li a').click();
```

The application should open a new tab of the browser and change the URL there.

How can I test the URL in the new instance of browser tab.

Comment: It looks like this is from the AngularJS tutorial. It's worth noting that this is an Angular E2E test, which has syntax inspired by Jasmine but is NOT Jasmine. Generally, Jasmine is a unit test framework and you should be mocking out functionality such as routing and opening new tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know any website which is a good place for me to start?

Comment: Jasmine has a pretty good tutorial at http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/  If you're looking for info on mocking out services such as $http, check out http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing and http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject  Other than that, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to test, it would help to have more context.